# Как перевести число из десятичной системы в шестнадцатиричную на Golang?

Tags: алгоритм, golang, системы-счисления, hex

Недавно, в ходе реализации одного алгоритма на Golang, нужно было реализовать перевод числа из десятичной системы счисления в шестнадцатиричную. Подскажите, как это возможно сделать на golang без использования сторонних библиотек? Просто в пакете strconv я не нашел ничего, что могло бы удовлетворить моим условиям. Заранее спасибо :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пожалуйста, озвучте ваши условия. Почему вам не подошли функции [`strconv.FromatInt(i int64, base int) string`](https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#FormatInt) и [`func FormatUint(i uint64, base int) string`](https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#FormatInt)?

https://go.dev/play/p/UbAVYlZAbtT

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    x := int64(12345678)
    x_hex := strconv.FormatInt(x, 16)
    fmt.Println(x_hex)
}
```

Результат `bc614e`

Answer (score 0):

```
import "fmt"

func main() {
    var num int = 2748
    fmt.Printf("Hex: %x\n", num) // abc
    fmt.Printf("Hex: %X\n", num) // ABC
}
```